# rsyslog client not working as a rsyslog server after a role change

Tags: linux, centos7, rsyslog

I have a linux machine and I configured this as a rsyslog client by adding the following entry into the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:

```
*.* @<rsyslog-server-IP-Address>:514
```

And it was working fine.
Then I tried to make the same linux machine as a rsyslog server (instead of rsyslog client) by adding the following entries into the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/RemoteHost/%fromhost%/programname/%programname%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
```

But, it is not working as a rsyslog server. 
Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Does your server ruleset `$template RemoteLogs ...` come before the `*.* @<rsyslog-server-IP-Address>:514` ? Otherwise the forwarding rule will block anything from going to the server rule.

I imagine you used [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-rsyslog-centralized-logging-in-centos-ubuntu/) as reference, if not give it a glance it will be useful. How does your config look like, does rsyslog provide any error?

Comment: The problem isn't the config itself. The problem is, that the OP is trying to **receive** logs on the server with the same config as he is **sending** logs on his client. The only useful information here is the provided link.